# Did I solve the system of equations correctly and if yes, how would the set of solution look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I wanted to ask whether I solved the following system of equations correctly:

> Solve the following  (augmented matrix, right vector is the solution vector)
> $$
>  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
>     -4 & -8 & 8 & -8 & 12 \\
>     0 & -6 & 0 & -12 & 6\\
>     -6 & -6 & 12 & 0 & 12
>   \end{array}\right]
> $$

I solved it this far:

> $$
>  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
>     1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -2 \\
>     0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & -1\\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
>   \end{array}\right]
> $$

Is it correct and if yes how would I express the set of solutions?

Comment: can you provide the steps you took to get to your result? Rather than just pasting it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. If you follow the standard procedure, what you should get is$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac12 \end{array}\right].$$Therefore, the set of solutions is$$\left\{\left(x,0,1+\frac x2,-\frac12\right)\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You need one more step to zero the $(1,2)$-entry.
The general solution will have $x_3$ and $x_4$ as free variables.

To check the preliminary work that you showed, write each of your
original rows as a linear combination of the first two rows of the reduced form.